# How to find the button within nested div tag through Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

First i'm newbie with Selenium for python.And my problem is :
I want to find button to auto click . Here is my code button :

```
<div class="check-button button-display">   
<div class="side-way side-way_left">
    <div class="side-button-test middle" >
        <div class="label">Click here !</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I try to :

`browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".side-button-test.middle")` , but it doesn't working.Can anyone help me .

Comment: What does it mean `not working`? How can we help if you are not specifying what exactly is wrong? Which error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.side-button-test.middle>div')))
element.click()
```

Please check for **iframe** , if it is in `iframe/frameset` , 
you will have to switch the focus of your **webdriver** like this :

```
browser.switch_to.frame(web element)
```

It is always a good practice if you switch back the focus of your driver back to main content after done with the current frame , you can try this code for that :

```
browser.switch_to.defaultContent();
```

Though you can try this xpath too :

```
//div[contains(text(),'Click here !')]
```

in this case, code would be :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[contains(text(),'Click here !')]')))
element.click()
```

Comment: Thank for  your rely , but it doesn't work . it throw error : Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".side-button-test middle>div"}

Comment: you have written this .side-button-test middle>div   , and I have provided you this : .side-button-test.middle>div

Comment: see the . before middle>div , it is missing in your case. Btw I have updated my answer check it out.

Comment: You invest so much time on the question, where we don't even know what is a problem and which error OP has

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov : I believe he has shared the error trace in comment section.

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov : yep , that is true

Comment: Solve problem with switch to frame ! Thank you

Comment: You can accept this answer, by clicking on check mark which is just under the down vote button and besides my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with Xpath,

```
find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Click here !')]")
```

Comment: @LoiHu what we meant to  "It doesn't work" you should provide error stack so we can trace exception.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared to click on the element with text as **Click here !** you need to induce *WebDriverwait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.side-way.side-way_left > div.side-button-test.middle > div.label"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='side-way side-way_left']/div[@class='side-button-test middle']/div[@class='label'][contains(.,'Click here !')]"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```